# Razor in asp.net core is very slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I created small asp.net core mvc project to test the speed of the asp.net application on the Linux (Ubuntu 16.04).

I created the CRUD controller that works with the AspUser class (stored in the PostgreSQL database). When I call the index method that shows the list of stored users the razor rendering is extremely slow. It takes 2 seconds to render the content (it is not the first call - the first call takes 8 seconds). There are 1000 users in the database.

The wrk utility wrk -c 256 -t 32 -d 10 http://localhost:5000/aspusers shows 2,6 request per second.
I made the same example in the nodejs the wrk utility shows 20 requests per second.

HW: Amd FX 8150 8 Core, 3.6 GHz, 8 GB RAM

Does anybody have an idea why is the view rendering so slow?

Model:

```
[Table("asp_users")]
public class AspUser
{
    [Column("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("first_name")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class AspUsersController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var users = await _context.AspUsers.OrderBy(a => a.Age).ToListAsync();
        return View(users);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PostgresTest.Models.AspUser>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedAt)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdatedAt)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Age
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.FirstName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.LastName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.CreatedAt
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.UpdatedAt
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting enough on the development machine (Win7 x64, dotnet core tools + SDK) it works pretty fast but on Win Server 2012R2 (only DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting is installed) it is super slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a seprate Model for data from database and ViewModel

for eg:

ViewModel

```
public class ViewAspUser
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

DataClass

```
public class DataAspUser
{
    [Column("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

This will work because i had faced the same issue.Then finally i had separated the class.This is because if you use the model with dataannotation it will connect to database everytime when you access your razor in View.

Comment: Not If you use to list()

Comment: I did that even. Still, I feel the page postback is slow. If you achieve using ajax. It's damn faster!